# camera as the background

Tags: c#, background, camera, directx, sharpdx

I've ran into a couple of problems when trying to use notebook webcam preview in app.

I'm trying hard to use the camera as the background for 3D models in Xaml.

Let me put it that way:
- XAML is the top layer, that holds all necessary controls like buttons, text and so on;
- DirectX is the layer that renders all the stuff behind Xaml

You can show the preview from camera using Xaml and .NET . Unfortunately, the preview shows on top of DirectX layer, covering all the 3D objects (which is unexpected behaviour).

What I'm trying to find is a workaround for that problem.

There is a way of making Xaml-DirectX-Xaml layer order using SurfaceImageSource, but it takes a lot of effort and low-level programming.

Hope you might help me find the solution for that particular problem.